# Sorting the results from a Filtered Query

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

Due to a large amount of filter terms (permissions system in the 1000s) I have to use `Elastic_Query_Filtered` which is fine and I can even set limits for pagination using

```
$elasticaType->search($elasticaQueryString, $options);
```

It all works quite well until I introduce the sort option. Here's what I have so far:

```
$options = array('from'=>$from, 'size'=>$to, 'sort'=>array("description" => array("order" => "asc")));
$elasticaResultSet = $elasticaType->search($elasticaQueryString, $options);
```

Am I doing something stupid or is sorting just not supported yet. Is there an alternative. Using a bool filter was making things hit the `max_clause_count`.

Comment: Did you found the solution to this problem? ``\Elastica\Query\Filtered`` does not seam to have ``setSort()`` method, like regular query does.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to search on single query string, with limit and sorting

```
$client = new Elastica_Client(array('host' => '192.168.0.27','port' => '9200'));

$elasticaQueryString =new Elastica_Query_QueryString();
$elasticaQueryString->setDefaultOperator('AND');
$elasticaQueryString->setQuery('100009'); // set value for where condition
$elasticaQueryString->setFields(array('increment_id','entity_id','billing_name'));  // set where fields

$elasticaQuery = new Elastica_Query();
$elasticaQuery->setQuery($elasticaQueryString);  // set query string
$elasticaQuery->setFields(array('increment_id','entity_id','billing_name','created_at'));   // set output fields

$elasticaQuery->setFrom(0); //set from point   
$elasticaQuery->setLimit(20);  //limit the record   
$sort = array("entity_id" => array("order" => "asc"));  //order by clause

$elasticaQuery->setSort($sort);  //set Sorting

echo "<br />".json_encode($elasticaQuery->toArray())."<br />";  //print the query

$search = new Elastica_Search($client); // Create the search object and inject the client
$resultSet = $search->addIndex('sales')->addType('order')->search($elasticaQuery);  // Configure and execute the search

echo "<br /><strong>Total Results Found : ".$totalResults= $resultSet->getTotalHits()."</strong><br />";            //get total result found

$data=$resultSet->getResults(); //extract the result

$result=array();

foreach ($data as $data1) 
{
  $result[]=$data1->getData();
}

print_r($result);
```